# Why isn't OpenGL drawing anything?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

This code is supposedly the code to draw a triangle however all I get is a black screen. Why am I not getting anything drawn?

Secondly, in my array of vertices, if I put an 'f' after my coordinates like I always see in tutorials I get an error about an invalid digit in an octal. Why can everyone else use 'f' after their numbers and not me?

I am using openGL 4.1 on OSX Yosemite.

```
  #include <iostream>
    //Using SDL and standard IO
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
    //#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
    //#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
    #include <GLUT/glut.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
    #include <glm/glm.hpp>
    #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
    #include <string.h>

using namespace std;


//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;



bool SetOpenGLAttributes()
{
    // Set our OpenGL version.
    // SDL_GL_CONTEXT_CORE gives us only the newer version, deprecated functions are disabled
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    return true;
}



int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        SetOpenGLAttributes();
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //creating new context
            SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

            GLuint vertexArrayID;
            glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
            glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);


            printf("%s", "This is your version");
            printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
            printf("%s", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));

            SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


            float r = 0.5;
            static const GLfloat cubeV[] = {
              -.5, 0, 0,
                .5, 0, 0,
                0, .5, 0

            };

            GLuint vertexBuffer;
            glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeV), cubeV, GL_STATIC_DRAW);





            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

            bool running = true;
            while(running){
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                                      0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but   must match the layout in the shader.
                                      3,                  // size
                                      GL_FLOAT,           // type
                                      GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                                      0,                  // stride
                                      (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                                      );

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

                glFlush();
                SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
                SDL_Delay(17);

            }


        }
    }


    //Destroy window
    //SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    //SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `glGetError` return anything after you draw stuff?

Comment: Where is your shader? Drawing in OpenGL Core Profile requires you to have one.

Comment: "*Secondly, in my array of vertices, if I put an 'f' after my coordinates like I always see in tutorials I get an error about an invalid digit in an octal. Why can everyone else use 'f' after their numbers and not me?*" Have you noticed that, when *they* do it, they have *decimal points* in their numbers?

Comment: @immibis The error output is 1282. BDL, I had been wondering if I needed a shader but the tutorial I am looking at displays a white triangle without shaders, and then goes on to add shaders to color the triangle. Nicol Bolas, I've put in decimals. I've even copied and pasted code from the tutorials and I still get the same error.

Comment: @user2905256 Probably, the tutorial is outdated or so. OpenGL > 3.2 core profile lacks default pipeline and requires you to provide both vertex and fragment shaders.